# Here maps won't display if not visible from start

Tags: bootstrap-4, here-api

I'm try to include Here Maps in my web application. The map should be shown after the user clicked a button/link to expand a bootstrap collapsable panel.

If I put the div containing the map outside of the collapsable panel it's working.

My Code in a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lymbzfx2/

My HTML

```html
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button">
    Link with href
  </a>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    <div id="map" class="chart"></div> <!-- Map should be here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

My JS code

```js
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    'app_id': '{App_ID}',
    'app_code': '{APP_Code}'
});

  // Obtain the default map types from the platform object:   
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

// Instantiate (and display) a map object:
var map = new H.Map(
  document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.normal.map, {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {
      lat: 52.5,
      lng: 13.4
    }
});
```

I expect the map to be shown after i click the "Link with href" link. However some of the SVGs from Here Maps is shown and no map tiles are loaded

Edit:
Added screenshot of the current state https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF2pi.png (Missing reputation to post the image)

Comment: take a screen from console section inspect element of your browser to show errors and send to check

Comment: There are no errors on the console. The canvas from Here Maps is initialized with 0px width and 0px height.
https://imgur.com/THW5P45.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HERE map canvas dynamically takes the width and height of its parent div (in this case: `<div id="map" class="chart"></div>`).

So, first you have to add `width` and `height` to the map div like so:

`<div id="map" style="width:100%; height:400px" class="chart"></div>`.

Secondly, you should note that child elements within a Bootstrap collapsable element will have their width and height equal to zero when collapsed (`display: none`) and their actual values when expanded (`display: block`).

So the HERE map should be drawn when the collapsable element is expanded (so that the map can have non-zero width and height). You can use JQuery to check if your button/link is clicked and the 'map' div is visible.

Comment: As you suggested I added a click eventlistener on the button. just in this event i added the map. Then everything was as expected.

Comment: @JB can you explain what you did for your map to make it work e.g paste the code if possible, in my case i'm working with bootstrap modal and thanks in advance

Comment: I just added the map after the element, which holds the map, was created.